# How to read uploaded json file Content in Reactive Spring WEBFlux(Spring 5)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipart, spring-webflux

Am uploading an json file in Spring WEB Flux application as shown below

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> uploadfile(ServerRequest request) { 

return request.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData()).flatMap(p -> {  
      FilePart filePart = (FilePart)p.toSingleValueMap().get("file");

      Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer1 = filePart.content();
      //Here i want to read the content of my uploaded json file 

});
return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(Mono.just("SUCCESS"), String.class); 
}
```

Can you help me in how can i extract json file content here.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public Mono<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart) {
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("test", filePart.filename());
    filePart.transferTo(tempFile);
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(tempFile.toUri());
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    return Mono.just(content);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.